# react-native-navbar issue with layout

Tags: javascript, node.js, facebook, reactjs, react-native

I don't know why but the navbar makes the content not fully cover the view ?

The code contains the navbar and side menu.

Don't worry about code related to keyboard events and icons.
Docit is where app initialize and have sidemenu code. Then the sidemenu has child element of navigation and here the navbar gets initialized.

```
'use strict';

var React = require('react-native');
var {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  Navigator,
  ScrollView,
} = React;

var { Icon, } = require('react-native-icons');

var SideMenu = require('react-native-side-menu');
var NavigationBar = require('react-native-navbar');

// require the module
var KeyboardEvents = require('react-native-keyboardevents');

// Now get a handle on the event emitter and add your callbacks
// to the desired events.
var KeyboardEventEmitter = KeyboardEvents.Emitter;

// Each event will receive a `frames` object, which contains three keys -
// `begin`,  `end`, and `duration` . The `begin` and `end`  keys each
// contain an object describing the bounds of the keyboard (x, y, width
// and height). The `duration` key contains the length of the keyboard
// animation in seconds.

// The frame in `begin` describes the bounds of the keyboard before the
// animation occurred and the frame in `end` describes the bounds the keyboard
// will have, after the animation has completed.
KeyboardEventEmitter.on(KeyboardEvents.KeyboardWillShowEvent, (frames) => {
  console.log('will show', frames);
});

KeyboardEventEmitter.on(KeyboardEvents.KeyboardDidShowEvent, (frames) => {
  console.log('did show', frames);
});

KeyboardEventEmitter.on(KeyboardEvents.KeyboardWillHideEvent, (frames) => {
  console.log('will hide', frames);
});

KeyboardEventEmitter.on(KeyboardEvents.KeyboardDidHideEvent, (frames) => {
  console.log('did hide', frames);
});

KeyboardEventEmitter.on(KeyboardEvents.KeyboardWillChangeFrameEvent, (frames) => {
  console.log('will change', frames);
});

KeyboardEventEmitter.on(KeyboardEvents.KeyboardDidChangeFrameEvent, (frames) => {
  console.log('did change', frames);
});

// Start of the Layout
var Menu = React.createClass({
  about: function() {
    this.props.menuActions.close();
    // this.props.navigator.push({...});
  },

  render: function() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>Menu</Text>
        <Text onPress={this.about}>About</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
});

var ContentView = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.welcome}>
          Welcome to React Native!
        </Text>
        <Text style={styles.instructions}>
          To get started, edit index.ios.js
        </Text>
        <Icon
          name='fontawesome|facebook-square'
          size={70}
          color='#3b5998'
          style={styles.facebook}
        />
        <Text style={styles.instructions}>
          Press Cmd+R to reload,{'\n'}
          Cmd+D or shake for dev menu
        </Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
});

// App Initialization with the Sidebar
var Docit = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    var menu = <Menu navigator={navigator}/>;

    return (
      <SideMenu menu={menu}>
        <NavigationBarView/>
      </SideMenu>
    );
  }
});

// Navigation with Content View
var NavigationBarView = React.createClass({

  renderScene: function(route, navigator) {
    var Component = route.component;
    var navBar = route.navigationBar;

    if (navBar) {
      navBar = React.addons.cloneWithProps(navBar, {
        navigator: navigator,
        route: route
      });
    }

    return (
      <View style={styles.navigator}>
        {navBar}
        <Component navigator={navigator} route={route} />
      </View>
    );
  },

  render: function() {
    return (
      <Navigator
        style={styles.navigator}
        renderScene={this.renderScene}
        initialRoute={{
          component: ContentView,
          navigationBar: <NavigationBar title="Initial View"/>
        }}
      />
    );
  }
});

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FC33',
  },
  welcome: {
    fontSize: 20,
    textAlign: 'center',
    margin: 10,
  },
  instructions: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: '#333333',
    marginBottom: 5,
  },
  facebook: {
    width: 70,
    height: 70,
    margin: 10
  },
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('Docit', () => Docit);
```

[image: Navbar Issue]

[image: The code also has side-menu with navbar]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out the issue. It's with the styling of navigator.

```
styles.navigator
```

If one includes in stylesheet this code, it will adjust to full view.

```
navigator: {
    flex: 1,
},
```